# how to get child of child of child data in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase database picture]

How can i get those data?

I'm getting issue in key value, because that is push key here is my some code of saving data first I'm adding.

creating table like

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("COURSE");
String courseId = reference.push().getKey();
if (courseId != null) {
    CourseTObject object = new CourseTObject();
    object.setcId(courseId);
    object.settId(firebaseUser.getUid());
    object.setInstitute(instituteName);
    object.setCourse(courseName);
    if (section.equals("")){
        object.setSection(null);
    }else {
        object.setSection(section);
    }
    reference.child(courseId).setValue(object);
}
```

add some data

```
reference = reference.child(nodeId).child(quizTitleString);
reference.child("totalQuestions").setValue(questions);
reference.child("timeLimit").setValue(timer);
reference.child("eachQuestionMarks").setValue(marks);
reference.child("quizTitle").setValue(quizTitleString);
```

then some child data mention below

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("COURSE");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            CourseTObject courseObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(CourseTObject.class);
            assert courseObject != null;
            if (courseObject.gettId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                if (courseObject.getInstitute().equals(institute)){
                    if (courseObject.getCourse().equals(course)){
                        if (courseObject.getSection().equals(section)){
                            String nodeId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                            assert nodeId != null;
                            reference = reference.child(nodeId).child(quizTitleString).child("QUESTION"+questionNo);
                            reference.child("question").setValue(q);
                            reference.child("choice1").setValue(c1);
                            reference.child("choice2").setValue(c2);
                            reference.child("choice3").setValue(c3);
                            reference.child("choice4").setValue(c4);
                            reference.child("answer"+answerNo).setValue(answer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

model class CourseTObject there is just some getter setter exclude child of child nodes data

```
public class CourseTObject {
    private String cId;
    private String tId;
    private String institute;
    private String course;
    private String section;
    private String totalQuestions;
    private String timeLimit;
    private String eachQuestionMarks;

    public CourseTObject() {
    }

    public CourseTObject(String cId, String tId, String institute, String course, String section, String totalQuestions, String timeLimit, String eachQuestionMarks) {
        this.cId = cId;
        this.tId = tId;
        this.institute = institute;
        this.course = course;
        this.section = section;
        this.totalQuestions = totalQuestions;
        this.timeLimit = timeLimit;
        this.eachQuestionMarks = eachQuestionMarks;
    }

    public String getcId() {
        return cId;
    }
    public void setcId(String cId) {
        this.cId = cId;
    }

    public String gettId() {
        return tId;
    }
    public void settId(String tId) {
        this.tId = tId;
    }

    public String getInstitute() {
        return institute;
    }
    public void setInstitute(String institute) {
        this.institute = institute;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }
    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getTotalQuestions() {
        return totalQuestions;
    }
    public void setTotalQuestions(String totalQuestions) {
        this.totalQuestions = totalQuestions;
    }

    public String getTimeLimit() {
        return timeLimit;
    }
    public void setTimeLimit(String timeLimit) {
        this.timeLimit = timeLimit;
    }

    public String getEachQuestionMarks() {
        return eachQuestionMarks;
    }
    public void setEachQuestionMarks(String eachQuestionMarks) {
        this.eachQuestionMarks = eachQuestionMarks;
    }    
}
```

Comment: add your CourseTObject model class code as well.

Comment: sure but there is noting

Comment: Your model class seems totally different from your database structure, how you're expecting the match of tid and uuid? if I am not wrong then uuid is equal to your course key for each child. Then tid should be dataSnapshot.getKey()

Comment: yeah you are right its looking diff cuz model class is incomplete and in contain data without child like teacher id those data is from different table as i mention class start and i'm getting key successful dataSnapshot.getKey() but my point is that how do that corret and see full table snap im update that

Comment: now check all things updated in Question

Comment: which data you referring to get?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at this code:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("COURSE");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            CourseTObject courseObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(CourseTObject.class);
            ...
```

So you're loading all the data at `COURSE` in your database, then loop over the direct child nodes (so `-N9...` in your screenshot), and then try to read a `CourseTObject` from those.

If we look at the screenshot of your database however, there are no `cId`, `tId`, `institude` and similar properties in that **direct** child node. Those properties live one level lower, under `QUIZ_1`.

Things should get better of you add a second loop:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("COURSE");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot pushkeySnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
           for (DataSnapshot quiz1Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                CourseTObject courseObject = quiz1Snapshot.getValue(CourseTObject.class);
                ...
```